# How to understand why CloudFront returns 301?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have a distribution in CloudFront pointing to a custom origin. It worked just fine for more than five years and just a few weeks ago started to return 301 for all requests. The origin works as before, SSL certificates are valid both at the CloudFront endpoint and at the origin.  The configuration of the "behavior" I didn't change in CloudFront. What could be the problem and how can I understand where is it?

If it helps, here is the URL: `https://djk1be5eatcae.cloudfront.net/?u=https://www.yegor256.com/index.html`. The origin that it points to is `relay.jare.io`. Thus, the URL to be used to fetch the content is this: `https://relay.jare.io/?u=https://www.yegor256.com/index.html` (works for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a misconfiguration in the "Behavior" of the CloudFront distribution. The SSL version was set to TLS1.2, while my origin only supports SSLv3. Changing the version to SSLv3 fixed the problem.